# $I(X,Y,Z)$ and $I(X\bigcup Y,Z,W) \ge I(X,Y,W)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian

I am trying to prove if $I(X,Y,Z)$ and $I(X\bigcup Y,Z,W)=> I(X,Y,W)$.
I know that $I(X,Y|Z)=I(Y,X|Z)$ and $I(X,W|Z\bigcup Y)$ and $I(X,Y|Z) \Rightarrow I(X,Y\bigcup W|Z)$, unable to use the above the axioms, to the question. Can anyone explain what needs to be done here?

Comment: Can you give context or explain your notations? What are $X$ and $Y$? What means $I(X,Y)$? Information? Indicator?

Comment: X and Y are disjoint sets. I(X,Y) means conditional independence of X with respect to Y